# On the Feynman's proof of Lorentz transformations

Tags: special-relativity

In [this](https://youtu.be/4pilyh2kKVo) video he explains Feynman way of deriving the Lorentz transformations.
First he considers the invariance,
$$ x^{2}-(ct)^{2}=(x')^{2}-(ct')^{2}$$

He then invokes a bit of complex analysis by letting $y=ict$ in the rotation of axes i.e
$$ x'=x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta)$$
$$y'=-x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta)$$

Then he explains that the trick is to let $\Delta x'=0$. And later he substitutes the assumption that $\Delta x'=0$ in the equation from rotation of axes i.e
$$x'=x\cos(\theta)+ict\sin(\theta)$$

And later deduces the fact that $v=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$.

**My question:-**

Why is $v=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$?

According to our assumption initially $x$ and $x'$ were the distances travelled by the beam of light in the times $t$ and $t'$ respectively. Then how does the velocity $v$ comes into play?

Comment: Hint: if $\Delta x'=0$, the primed coordinate system is a rest frame, so what's happening in the unprimed one?